# Windows 7 Deleting Drive Letter On Boot

Tags: windows

Wonder if anyone can help me please. I've got a Windows 7 build with an extra partition in which I'm storing a VHD the drive letter has been set to "U" using diskpart. However everytime I boot into Windows it deletes the drive letter and I have to re-assign it. Can't for the life of me work out what would be doing it.

I can't see anything in group policy that would cause it, there are no drive letter conflicts.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

it is apparently expected that vhds do not automatically mount at boot, but a batch file can automatically mount it for you. Check out the bottom half of this tutorial for details: http://www.techtipsgeek.com/create-permanently-attach-virtual-hard-disk-windows-7/12012/

Answer (score 0):

By default, windows 7 does not automatically mount VHD file and all mounted VHD files are unmounted at logoff. I do not know any option built into windows that allows you to change this behavior. This is different from mapped network drives, which can be remapped at logon. You have to load a script in your startup folder or do something similar, if you want windows to mount VHDs.

That said, I dislike mounting VHD through diskpart/windows disk management. I've run into issues (errors stating that the unmounted VHD file is in use) when I've unmounted the drives and attempted to mount them again - A simple logoff has not helped.

Hence, I use a 3rd party software called [Gizmo manager](http://arainia.com/software/gizmo/index.html) to mount and manage my VHD files. It includes an option to remount drives at windows startup.